# What do the operators + * and : do in gls function

Tags: r, linear-regression, nlme

My code looks like this:

```
Endo.v.Mass_Extant_Stages<-gls(log.Endo~log.Mb+Stage, data = CrocOntogenyData)
```

My results change based on whether I'm using a +,*, or : between log.Mb (continuous) and Stage (categorical). Does anyone actually know what these operators are doing? I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: See the *Details* section of the `?formula` help page - there is a common syntax for most all linear models in R described there.

Comment: These are explained in the help file - see `?lm` and look in the **Details** section, about 1/3 of the way down the page.

Comment: `model.matrix(Endo.v.Mass_Extant_Stages, CrocOntogenyData)` will show the model matrix that it used.

Answer (score 2):

Models in R have a special syntax described [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) (you can also type `help(formula)` into R). They aren't only used in the gls function (`lm` also uses them, for instance).

`Z ~ x + y` corresponds to the mathematical formula "z = ax + by + c" for every x and y value, for some constants a, b, c.

`Z ~ x * y` corresponds to the mathematical formula "z = ax + by + cxy + d" for every x and y value, for some constants a, b, c, d.

`Z ~ x / y` corresponds to the mathematical formula "z = ax + bxy + c" for every x and y value, for some constants a, b, c.

`Z ~ x:y` corresponds to the mathematical formula "z = axy" for every x and y value, for some constant a.

See [this Stack Exchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29329/what-is-the-meaning-of-operators-in-regression-or-anova-formulas-in-r) for more information

Comment: Your link to the help page is helpful, but your summary is wrong.  For example, `Z ~ x + y` means `E(Z) = a x + b y + c` for some `a`, `b` and `c` when `x` and `y` are continuous.

Comment: That's better.  Still, if `x` or `y` is a factor, things are different: e.g. instead of `ax`, you'd use `a_x` (i.e. `a[x]`) with a different constant for each `x` value.